# Recursive only 2 level records using common sql

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I have an `Employee` table, it's a self-referencing table, with `managerId` refers to primary key `empID`. I want to find 2 level records by a given `empId`.

For example: if given `empId=5`,
if `empId=5` has children records, display them, as well as the children in children records.
The database is SQL Server 2005.

**update:** I wanna a full projection out

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  Not sure what you mean by "full projection out".  If you mean every child of every child, then you'll need a loop.  But if you know you just want to go down 2 levels, this example will work:

```
SELECT
   t1.empID as Parent_ID,
   t2.empID as Child_ID,
   t3.empID as Grandchild_ID
FROM 
   employee t1
   LEFT JOIN employee t2 ON t1.empID = t2.managerID
   LEFT JOIN employee t3 ON t2.empID = t3.managerID
WHERE t1.empID = @given_empID
```